# How to apply filter on array of strings in Loopback?

Tags: arrays, api, filter, loopback

I need to filter an array of strings in loopback. I have the following model.

```
{
...
"type": ["string"],
...
}
```

The filters I'm using are `{"where":{"type":["filter string"]}}` and `{"type":["filter string"]}`, but both are not working and return all the entries.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `{"where":{"type":"filter string"}}` without square brackets. Since `type` is defined as an array of strings, this query will return entries with `filter string` as an element at any index.

Comment: Status is 200, but:

Response Headers
{
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=0; includeSubDomains",
  "via": "1.1 vegur",
  "vary": "Origin, Accept-Encoding",
  "server": "Cowboy",
  "etag": "W/\"2-l9Fw4VUO7kr8CvBlt4zaMCqXZ0w\"",
  "x-download-options": "noopen",
  "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "date": "Tue, 03 Oct 2017 17:05:41 GMT",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
  "content-length": "2",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
}

Comment: Is anything wrong with the response? I couldn't understand from your comment

Comment: No, actually the data is available in the table. When I just click on **try it out** , it gives me all the data present in the table regardless of **type** which I need to filter. I am not able to figure out the problem, the query is setup in the database and I have used Postgre for DB.

Comment: Postgre is a SQL database. My answer will not work for that as it stores data of array as a string. You have to use `regexp` or `ilike` in your query. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#ilike-and-nilike

Comment: Query would be: `{"where": {"type": {"ilike": "%\"filter string\"%"}}}`

Comment: It shows: 
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
  }
}

Comment: Do you have access to node console? Please share the error details. Also try `{"where": {"type": {"ilike": "%filter string%"}}}` as this is very similar to the example mentioned in the document.

Comment: I tried this too (mentioned above), its not working. I don't have node console. Error is:  { "error": { "statusCode": 500, "message": "Internal Server Error" } }
Actually when I try to filter out string with this query :
{"where":{"country":"India"}} it works well. But for the array of strings it doesn't work.